# How to Export and publish game flawlessly?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I finished my project and I cannot find anything on how to make sure your game is able to run java on all API levels, and phones. I have seen something about max api, and minimum. Do I have to export multiple apk's? I also don't know what other finishing touches are required for a final draft to upload to the playstore. Any tips on maximum compatibility (or whats needed), and things to look out for? I'm new to this. If you know of a very good tutorial that would work too. I am using Eclipse. Thanks alot.

Comment: Are you talking about an Android game?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Should have specified.

Comment: What should I set as the minimum api and max in the android manifest?

Comment: "target". not "max"